# Converting database from SQL-Server 2008 to SQL-Anywhere

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlanywhere

Please tell me about the main advantages of `SAP SQL-Anywhere` and the main differences it has with `SQL-server 2008`. While installing `SQL-server 2008` in various computer systems, the installation does not happen smoothly at times, so we try to solve this problem by using `SAP SQL-Anywhere`.

Is it possible to convert a `SQL-server 2008` database in to a `SAP SQL-Anywhere` database?

Comment: Have you read this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Anywhere ?, why did you tag Postgresql in your qn ?

Comment: thanks for the help Mr.Ashis Nitin Patil an Mr. w͏̢in̡͢g͘̕ed̨p̢͟a͞n͏͏t̡͜͝he̸r̴

Comment: So you figured out?